proving that $A_n/\operatorname{ker} \beta \cong \operatorname{ker} \alpha_{n - 1}.$
Prove that in any exact sequence $$\dots \xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+3}}A_{n+2} \xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+2}} A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+1}} A_{n} \xrightarrow{\alpha_{n}}  A_{n -1}\xrightarrow{\alpha_{n-1}} \dots $$ there is a short exact sequence $$0 \to \operatorname{coker} \alpha_{n+2} \xrightarrow{\alpha} A_n \xrightarrow{\beta} \operatorname{ker} \alpha_{n - 1} \to 0$$ where $\operatorname{coker} \alpha_{n+2} = A_{n+1}/\operatorname{im} \alpha_{n+2}$
I was able to define a new map $\alpha$ with same kernel as the kernel of $\alpha_{n+1}$ which made the left half of the required sequence injective and I was able to prove that the right half of it surjective, now it remains to show that $$A_n / \operatorname{im} \alpha = A_n / \operatorname{ker} \beta \cong \operatorname{ker} \alpha_{n - 1} $$ but I do not know how to prove it, I believe I should use the first isomorphism theorem but I do not know how. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Since you have already thought about this a bit, I will give you the details.
To do this canonically, let us start with the exact sequence
$$A_{n+1}\xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+1}}A_n\xrightarrow{\alpha_n} A_{n-1}.$$
If we restrict the codomain of $\alpha_n$ to its image, it becomes surjective by definition, i.e. the following is exact:
$$A_{n+1}\xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+1}}A_n\xrightarrow{\alpha_n} \text{im}(\alpha_n)\longrightarrow 0.$$
Further, if we look at $\alpha_{n+1}$, it induces an injective map (which I, by abuse of notation, also denote $\alpha_{n+1}$) from $A_{n+1}/\ker(\alpha_{n+1})$ to $A_n$, and it has the same image as the original $\alpha_{n+1}$. This means that the following is exact:
$$0\longrightarrow A_{n+1}/\ker(\alpha_{n+1})\xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+1}}A_n\xrightarrow{\alpha_n} \text{im}(\alpha_n)\longrightarrow 0.$$
Now all we are missing is translating this to the desired sequence. By exactness of the original sequence, we know that $\text{im}(\alpha_n)=\ker(\alpha_{n-1})$, and so can replace the former with the latter. Similarly, as $\ker(\alpha_{n+1})=\text{im}(\alpha_{n+2})$, we get that $A_{n+1}/\ker(\alpha_{n+1})=\text{coker}(\alpha_{n+2})$ by definition. Thus, we have the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow \text{coker}(\alpha_{n+2})\xrightarrow{\alpha_{n+1}}A_n\xrightarrow{\alpha_n} \ker(\alpha_{n-1})\longrightarrow 0.$$

but we need to prove an isomorphism as I mentioned, right? Where did you prove it?

This follows from how I chose my maps to begin with! Since the first sequence I write up is exact, because the long exact sequence is, and I never change the image of $\alpha_{n+1}$ nor the kernel of $\alpha_n$, the exactness is preserved. You made a small error in typing up what isomorphism you want: exactness in the middle is exactly $\text{im}(\alpha) = \ker(\beta)$.
